# Is there a way to reliably malloc the same block of memory as a previously freed block, then access the content that was previously in it?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, undefined-behavior

I have the following C program which requests some memory (`str1`), reads the content of a file into that space then frees it. Next, a block of the same size (`str2`) is requested, and the content is printed to stdout.

What I want is for `str2` to contain the content of `str1` so that the output is always the content of the file.

I am aware that what I am doing is undefined behaviour, in that I can't guarantee what the content of memory that has been allocated will contain. However, I'm trying to do some underhanded stuff for a demonstration where data from a file can be exfiltrated without it being obvious in a code review.

Almost all the time, I receive a block of memory at the same address for both `str1` and `str2`, and **most of the time** when I run the program on macOS and Windows, the content of the file is printed. It seems to never happen on Linux (on Linux, calling `free()` seems to zero out the memory block).

Is there a way of making this more reliable on Windows and macOS, and is there any explanation for why it doesn't work at all on Linux?

My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  char *str1 = malloc(4096*sizeof(char));
  fread(str1, 1, 4096, f);
  free(str1);
  
  char *str2 = malloc(4096);
  printf("Content: %s\n", str2);
  free(str2);
}
```

Comment: unless you write your own malloc this is there should be little guarantee, as it would be highly dependent on the c runtime you are using

Comment: @dvhh I am prepared to use a VM/Docker to ensure it always runs in the same environment, if there are any runtimes that are known to have the behaviour that I am looking for

Comment: If you ask about that kind of guarantee, then I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please try to take a logical step back and describe whatever it is you want to achieve by doing this. What you do describe in the question seems like you are freeing when you don't really want to and should not. Malloc is not a communication mechanism, you need to provide the non-freed pointer to the second part. Please clarify why this is not an option.

Comment: @Yunnosch, imagine that I'm going to allocate some memory then read something sensitive (e.g. a private key) into that block and do something with it. Later, I allocate some memory of the same size and stick some data into it that will be saved to a file. If I don't overwrite all the data in the block then it may contain some sensitive info that would get saved to the file. In that case, it may not be obvious from a code review that some sensitive data exfiltration is possible. I want to demonstrate that sensitive data can be exfiltrated in a non-obvious manner.

Comment: What about multithreading? Is this a single process or MT? AFAIK you can not even guarantee that your pointer sticks to the same page after you freed it. If you are worried about sensitive data, a potential attacker could access the memory from the outside by using `ReadMemory` or similar.

Comment: @Grezzo OK I've got your point. The point of undefined behaviour is that it's undefined. So if you want to make the demonstration you need to use an environnment (such as Windows or MacOS) where you get (most of the time at least) the behaviour you want. Apparently on Linux `malloc` works differently and memory is cleared somehow in between.

Comment: @klutt: The question clearly indicates the purpose. Op seeks to demonstrate malicious actor, such as an employee with access to the source code, can exploit properties of memory allocation to exfiltrate code in spite of code reviews that ensure memory is freed when it is no longer needed for the program’s intended purpose. Studying how software or hardware may be exploited by malicious actors is a valid and valuable pursuit.

Comment: I'm able to get the desired behavior pretty reliably on a CentOS 7 VM.  You could try using that for your demo.

Comment: Thank's @dbush, I found that it works on the Debian derived distro that I'm using too. I thought it wasn't working because I was storing a string in the memory and using printf. It appears that (unlike on macOS) on Linux, the first few bytes are "tampered with" when I malloced the same block and it was encountering a null byte that caused it to stop reading. When I use a larger chunk and inspect the bytes, I can still see most of my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, what happens when you allocate and free is a black box to you. There is absolutely no reliable way to get the same address. Calling `free` means that you tell the OS that you're done with the memory, and there's no undo for this.

> What I want is for str2 to contain the content of str1 so that the output is always the content of the file.

You basically have three options here.

1. Wait with the call to `free`
2. Copy the buffer before you call `free`
3. Write your very own implementation of `malloc` and `free`

From comments:

> imagine that I'm going to allocate some memory then read something sensitive (e.g. a private key) into that block and do something with it. Later, I allocate some memory of the same size and stick some data into it that will be saved to a file. If I don't overwrite all the data in the block then it may contain some sensitive info that would get saved to the file. In that case, it may not be obvious from a code review that some sensitive data exfiltration is possible. I want to demonstrate that sensitive data can be exfiltrated in a non-obvious manner.

Nice thing, but these kind of exploits almost always relies on *undefined behavior*. As you say yourself, it's a security concern. So there's really no point in providing a reliable way to do this.

Here is a snippet that worked for me on Fedora Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s = malloc(100);
    const char str[] = "Hello, World. Prepare to meet your doom.";
    strcpy(s, str);
    free(s);
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) 
        putchar(s[i]);
    puts("");
}
```

My output:

```
$ ./a.out 
��epare to meet your doom.
```

As you can see, I got parts of the data, but not all. And to demonstrate the undefined behavior of this, here is output with different optimizations:

```
$ gcc k.c -O1
$ ./a.out 
0Separe to meet your doom.
$ gcc k.c -O2
$ ./a.out 
@�
$ gcc k.c -O3
$ ./a.out 
�
```

Your method is very unreliable for this, because you will print until the first 0 in the string. Here is code that will output nothing, which can fool you that the data has been wiped. That's why I used `putchar` in a loop above.

```
char str[] = "Hello, World";
str[0] = '\0';
printf("%s", str); // Will print nothing, but only first character is wiped
```

Comment: I disagree with the statment "there's really no point in providing a reliable way to do this."

Good call with the null byte terminating the string. I think on Linux, the first few bytes are modified, but the majority of the data still stands. On macOS none of the data is modified, which is what made me think it worked there but not on Linux.

Comment: @Grezzo I guess you always can come up with a reason for anything if you really want to. But I'm pretty confident that ANY code that used such a feature would be heavily criticized for being bad designed. And rightly so. The moment you call `free` the OS can do whatever it wants with the memory. Imagine you're renting a flat, and after some time you move out. But maybe you're curious about how the next person renting the flat has decorated it. Would you find it sensible that your former landlord provided a way for you to see that?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to reliably malloc the same block of memory as a previously freed block

Yes, use `realloc` instead of `free` + `malloc`. Otherwise there's no reliable or safe way to get the exact amount at the same address.

> I receive a block of memory at the same address for both str1 and str2

Well there's not much else going on in this simple program, so perhaps no wonder. There's no guarantees though. Also, unless you actually do a write access to the heap, the memory allocation might not actually be called. So `str2` could just be some random address in case the whole malloc call gets optimized away. Or alternatively, malloc is called but the OS never allocates any actual memory.

> is there any explanation for why it doesn't work at all on Linux?

I don't know but I suspect [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) might have something to with it. Some Linux guru will have to answer that part.